# Wordcount in C program

Tags: c, word-count

I am trying to write a program that counts the number of words in a text file in c, how would i go about doing so? I am not looking for the code so much as the pseudocode for how this would be accomplished?

Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556203/counting-words-in-a-string/13556241#13556241 but apply to file rather than string.

Comment: same question asked by the same user. 1 hour ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420488/wordcounting-program-in-c

Answer (score 0):

it would be a word every time the user insert a space, new line or tab. If any of these characters are entered you would have to increment the word counter like this

```
if ( character == '\n' || character == '\t' || character == ' ')
    ++wordCounter;
```

This is supposing you're using getchar()